# The meaning of linearity of Expectation

Tags: probability

I am reading a book which is Probabilistic method. They have a solution for "Balancing vector problem". Here is the solution

> 2.4 BALANCING VECTORS
> The next result has an elegant non-probabilistic proof, which we defer to the end of this chapter. Here, $|v|$ is the usual Euclidean norm.

Theorem 2.4.1 Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in R^n$, all $\left|v_i\right|=1$. Then there exist $\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_n= \pm 1$ so that
$$
\left|\epsilon_1 v_1+\cdots+\epsilon_n v_n\right| \leq \sqrt{n}
$$
and also there exist $\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_n= \pm 1$ so that
$$
\left|\epsilon_1 v_1+\cdots+\epsilon_n v_n\right| \geq \sqrt{n}
$$
Proof. Let $\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_n$ be selected uniformly and independently from $\{-1,+1\}$. Set
$$
X=\left|\epsilon_1 v_1+\cdots+\epsilon_n v_n\right|^2
$$
Then
$$
X=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_i \epsilon_j v_i \cdot v_j .
$$
Thus
$$
\mathrm{E}[X]=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n v_i \cdot v_j \mathrm{E}\left[\epsilon_i \epsilon_j\right]
$$
When $i \neq j, \mathrm{E}\left[\epsilon_i \epsilon_j\right]=\mathrm{E}\left[\epsilon_i\right] \mathrm{E}\left[\epsilon_j\right]=0$. When $i=j, \epsilon_i^2=1$ so $\mathrm{E}\left[\epsilon_i^2\right]=1$. Thus
$$
\mathrm{E}[X]=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i \cdot v_i=n .
$$
Hence there exist specific $\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_n= \pm 1$ with $X \geq n$ and with $X \leq n$. Taking square roots gives the theorem.\

**My problem:** I don't understand the last statement. I don't know why when we have $\mathrm{E}[X]=n$ then there exist specific $\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_n= \pm 1$ with $X \geq n$ and with $X \leq n$. I guess that it is because we have $\mathrm{P}[X \ge n] >0$. But how to prove that?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This last part is not because of linearity of expectation (linearity of expectation was used before in the proof).

This part uses the fact that a random variable with finite expectation $\alpha$ must have positive probability to be at least $\alpha$: if $\mathbb{E}[X] = \alpha$, then $\Pr[X \geq \alpha] > 0$. (Same for probability to be *at most* $\alpha$). That is, "a random variable cannot always be strictly less than its expectation."

Comment: Can we prove that property ?

Comment: @Pipnap for a discrete random variable (as you have here), yes, quite easily (try it!): for the general case, it's just a little bit more annoying, see e.g., Theorem 2.2.1 here: https://people.math.wisc.edu/~roch/mdp/roch-mdp-chap2.pdf

Comment: Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is equivalent to say that the mean value is always between the minimum and the maximum values of the random variable.
Let us assume that $X$ takes the values $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_m$ with probabilities $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_m$, respectively. Also, assume without loss of generality that $a_1 \le a_2 \le \dots \le a_m$. Then,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \sum_{i_1}^m p_i a_i \le \sum_{i_1}^m p_i a_m = a_m \\
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \sum_{i_1}^m p_i a_i \ge \sum_{i_1}^m p_i a_1 = a_1
\end{align}
or $a_1 \le \mathbb{E}[X] \le a_m$.

So, in your case, if $\mathbb{E}[X]=n$, there are two option: either $X$ is equal to $n$ for all $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n$, or $X$ is less than $n$ for some $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n$ and larger than $n$ for some others (cannot be always larger or always smaller because of the property above). Note that the two cases can be summarized by saying "there exist specific $\epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_n=\pm 1$ with $X\ge n$ and with $X\le n$."

But we can go a bit further - assume that we have a specific $\epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_n=\pm 1$ such that $X=n$ and assume $\epsilon_n= 1$ (the case $\epsilon_n= -1$ is very similar). Let
$$
w=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \epsilon_i v_i
$$
so that
$$
n=X=\lvert w + v_n\rvert^2=\lvert w\rvert^2 + \lvert v_n\rvert^2 + 2 w\cdot v_n.
$$
Now, let's change the sign of $\epsilon_n$. We have
$$
\lvert w - v_n\rvert^2=\lvert w\rvert^2 + \lvert v_n\rvert^2 - 2 w\cdot v_n = n - 4 w\cdot v_n
$$
meaning that, unless $v_n$ is orthogonal to $w$, you can always find a tuple $\epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_n=\pm 1$ such that $X \ne n$.